# how to scrape twitter for a whole country using twint library

Tags: python, geocode, twint

Hello I want to ask a question regarding scraping tweets from the Twitter using Twint library

Basically, to **scrape** tweet from a specific location, it is needed to put geocoded data which is consist of 'latitude, longitude, radius'

So my question here is how do I **scrape** the tweets in the whole Indonesia?
If i need to use the geocode, so the coordinate will be `coor_ind = '4.2105, 101.9758, radius(km)`
how do I determine the radius that covers the whole Indonesia?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 1):

First up, you might not get every tweet - because some tweets might not have location on them.

But you can use the `c.near` for cities in Indonesia.

An example is available on [this Medium article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-scrape-tweets-and-create-dataset-using-twint-without-twitter-api-e5890c25d1c9).